# How to force commit nested transaction in rails (4.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have nested transaction example. From `Aclass#call` method, I am calling `BClass#call` method within transaction block.
Now in `Bclass call` method does not commit  transaction till `Aclass call` method transaction block is completely executed.

How can I force `Bclass#call` method to commit transaction.

```
class Aclass
  def call
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      Bclass.new.call()
      # other logic to  save some record
    end 

    #publish event to Rabbit Queue 
    publish
  end
end


class Bclass
  def call
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      # save some record in.
    end

    #publish some event to rabbit queue
    publish
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly used DBMS's (including MariaDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL) do not supported nested transactions on their own. That is: the database does not support what you want to do.

Rails emulates some aspects of nested transactions (specifically the ability to rollback) using `SAVEPOINT`s, which act as a snapshot within a transaction. With these, you can rollback the state of a transaction to some previous savepoint. However, they do not allow to commit some changes before the actual "outer-most" transaction is actually committed. Only this outer-most transaction can actually commit changes which are then visible to other concurrent transactions.